# Hide and Show the Floating Button While ListView Scrolls

Tags: android, listview, onscrolllistener

I am creating a listView and a floating button in my application and I would like to have the effect of hiding and returning depending on the scroll state. When the `ListView` is being Scrolled the button hides fine, but when the scrolling stops the button does not return to its initial position.

Any ideas?

My Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private ImageButton btn;
    private ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final String[] items = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5", "item 6", "Item 7", "Item 8", "Item 9", "Item 10", "Item 11", "Item 12", "Item 13", "Item 14", "item 15"};
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have selected " + items[position].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

                if(scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL){
                    btn.animate().translationYBy(350);
                }else{
                    btn.animate().cancel();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            }
        });
        btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Floating Button Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This prevents the button to launch at short flinges:

```
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            int btn_initPosY=btn.getScrollY();
            if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                btn.animate().cancel();
                btn.animate().translationYBy(150);
            } else {
                btn.animate().cancel();
                btn.animate().translationY(btn_initPosY);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

for Android floating action button which reacts on scrolling events you can use this link :

https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton

Answer (score 4):

This will do what you want

```
lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

                if(scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL){
                    btn.animate().cancel();
                    btn.animate().translationYBy(350);
                }else{
                    btn.animate().cancel();
                    btn.animate().translationYBy(-350);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            }
        });
        btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Floating Button Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState){
        int btnPosY = buttonFab.getScrollY();
        if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
            buttonFab.animate().cancel();
            buttonFab.animate().translationYBy(150);
        } else if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_FLING) {
            buttonFab.animate().cancel();
            buttonFab.animate().translationYBy(150);
        } else {
            buttonFab.animate().cancel();
            buttonFab.animate().translationY(btnPosY);
        }

    }
```