# How to make date toast in image gallery while scrolling?

Tags: android, date, android-gridview, toast, image-gallery

I have created a sample gallery application using grid view and now i would 
like to add a toast with date of file created with the images like moto g,

[Sample Image](http://media2.giga.de/2014/01/moto-g-motorola-gallery-app.jpg)

given below is the method used to get list of images,

```
 public static String[] getAllImages(){

String[] rootFolders = MainActivity.getStorageDirectories();    

  if (rootFolders == null) 
  {
      return rootFolders;
  }
  int rl = rootFolders.length;

  for (int i = 0; i < rl; i++)
  {
      String path = rootFolders[i];
      File target = new File(path + "/DCIM/Camera/");
      if (target.exists()) 
      {
          File[] filelists = target.listFiles();
          if(common==null)
              common = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(filelists));
          else
              Collections.addAll(common, filelists);
      }
      File target2 = new File(path + "/DCIM/100ANDRO/");
      if (target2.exists()) 
      {
          File[] filelist = target2.listFiles();
          if(common == null)
              common = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(filelist));
          else
              Collections.addAll(common, filelist);
      }
  }
  int i = common.size();
  String[] list = new String[i];
  int counter = 0;    
  String name = null;
  String path = "file:///";
  for(File file : common)
  {
        date = new Date(file.lastModified());
        if(file.isFile())
            name = path+file.getAbsolutePath().toString();
            list[counter] = name;
            mThumbIds = new Integer[counter];
            counter++;
  }
return list;}
```

and getview() method to display image,

```
             String[] imagesurl = getAllImages(); 

    public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                        ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolder gridViewImageHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_grid_image, parent, false);
            gridViewImageHolder = new ViewHolder();
            gridViewImageHolder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            gridViewImageHolder.imageView.setMaxHeight(80);
            gridViewImageHolder.imageView.setMaxWidth(80);
            view.setTag(gridViewImageHolder);
        } else {

            gridViewImageHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
          imageLoader.displayImage(imagesURL[position], gridViewImageHolder.imageView,options);
          return view; 
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would you get the date of the images taken?

Comment: using file.lastmodified()

Comment: Create one button and put it at the position you want in the layout and keep updating the text of button by date. And make the button visible only when you scroll through gallery. May this help you to show and hide button http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513255/hide-and-show-the-floating-button-while-listview-scrolls

Comment: @Apurva Thanks, but i would like to have it in toast not in button sorry.

Comment: Can you not simply add `file.lastmodified().toString()` into toast message?

Comment: yes, we can but that will not give the complete solution whether it'll give current date or file created date, but i want to find date for each and every image which i show in application.